# Is it possible to convert a swift mt104 files to mt971 file?

Tags: swift-mt

I need to convert a MT104 files to MT971

http://www.iotafinance.com/en/SWIFT-ISO15022-Message-type-MT971.html
http://www.iotafinance.com/en/SWIFT-ISO15022-Message-type-MT104.html

Can somebody advice if this is technically possible and if yes how to do it easier?

Comment: The Swift tag that you have used is a Apple programming language. It probably is possible to convert these files as long as the required information is there, what have you tried, what language/environment are you planning on using to do this?

Comment: thank you, i'm now struggling with format details to understand if it has all the necessary data for convertation, as you said. But i wonder if somebody already had the similar experience and can advice something.. i did not decide about environment yet, so this is the also question. I need to parse file and re-save it with different structure, i suppose to choose python, but not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MT104 is a debit instruction message and MT971 is a Netting balance report, why would you want to convert one to another??

But anyway, you can use the library provided by prowidesoftware to parse/read and write the message in a different format.

https://www.prowidesoftware.com/resources/SWIFT-parser

https://www.prowidesoftware.com/resources/SWIFT-writer

https://www.prowidesoftware.com/products/core